# MainWindow.xaml File Not found in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf

I created a **MainWindow.xaml** file in visual studio. Then I clicked on run its working good. I created another file called **SecondMainWindow.xaml**, now I want to run the SecondMainWindow.xaml as the start file. But when I click run the MainWindow.xaml file is opening. So I excluded that file from the project. Now if I click run then it throw-ed an error saying

**MainWindow.xaml does not exist**.

Yes that is true because I have excluded it from my project.

But my question how to make **SecondMainWindow.xaml** as the file that should be opened first when I click on run.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In App.xaml under `StartupUri` attribute of `Application` tag change `MainWindow.xaml` to `SecondMainWindow.xaml`.

```
<Application StartupUri = "SecondMainWindow.xaml" >

</Application>
```

BTW there was no need of removing `MainWindow.xaml` from project. You can have n number of xaml files. What you define in `StartupUri` property is the file which is run first.

Comment: Thank u Nikhil. I was thinking and searching for this from last 30 mins. but StackOverFlow gave me answer in one minute.

Answer (score 2):

Set StartupUri to SecondMainWindow.xaml in your App.xaml

Answer (score 2):

Go to the App.xaml file and change StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml" to StartupUri="SecondMainWindow.xaml"